# Late March - Early April Boat trip from Bratislava to Vienna

Tags: public-transport, vienna, bratislava

I understand it's a nice thing to do, a little cruise on the Danube however I can't find concrete information whether there are cruises the first week of April (or end of March), I get the impression it's seasonal.

Alternatively what other reliable frequent transport is there from central Bratislava to central Vienna (not the airports)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Twin City Liner](http://www.twincityliner.com/en/content/bratislava-vienna) schedule could perhaps be laid out more clearly, but careful perusal shows that their season runs from 25 March 2016 to 30 October 2016.

Another option is the train; this is faster (1 hour), cheaper, and runs all year round, but of course isn't quite the same experience as a river cruise :). [Here is ÖBB's leaflet about the Vienna-Bratislava service](http://www.oebb.at/__downloads/de/Reisen_ins_Ausland/EURegio/BratisLover_2015.pdf), including a timetable.

Comment: This is better thanks, unfortunately the day I want to use it is off peak and not a weekend grr! Frequent trains though, could still start the trip in Bratislava.

Comment: You can hardly call the Twin City Liner a 'river cruise' anyway. It is a high-speed catamaran ferry with just about as much flair as any common city bus or subway.